# View border color: Why do I have to go through 'layer'

Tags: swift3

Som im working with a `chart framework` and i have a view called `lineChartView`. I wanted to see its `frame/bounds` so I tried

```
    lineChartView.borderLineWidth = 1
    lineChartView.borderColor = .red
```

This did not work, but I found a code to make it work:

```
    lineChartView.layer.borderWidth = 1          
    lineChartView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

What is the purpose of `layer` and why wont the first piece of code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly long history. `NSView` (Mac) didn't originally have layers. A "layer" is a GPU-enhanced canvas; there was a time before GPUs were ubiquitous, animations were run by `NSTimer`, and dinosaurs roamed the world. They added layers in 10.5 as part of Core Animation (which is mostly "GPU accelerated stuff"), but you had to ask for them with `wantsLayer`. Layers brought features like automatic borders and rounded corners along with tons of other features, but if you didn't need that, you could continue to use a standard `NSView`. When they wrote UIKit, they built it on top of the existing Core Animation `CALayer`, made all views layer-backed, and generally "modernized" a lot of stuff from `NSView`, but they didn't fundamentally change the division of API between view and layer. They could have added a whole bunch of pass-through wrapper methods (`view.borderColor` -> `view.layer.borderColor`), but they didn't.

Comment: Okey cool thanks Rob! So my best bet i just to try to remember the layer stuff and just keep putting .layer. in between?

Also when im not using .layer. the command is still executed, but it has no function? Or is there something getting a border color that just arent displayed?

Comment: `lineChartView.borderLineWidth = 1` shouldn't even compile. So it should be pretty clear when you need to add `.layer`. After a little experience, you'll likely get used to which things on are on the view and which are on the layer. It's not completely random. "Decorations" are generally on the layer.